# Using a "LIKE" clause for a reference/lookup list - SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-like

How would you create a lookup list that uses the LIKE clause for one or more fields?

I need to have a reference list that looks for exact values in some columns but partial values in others

E.g. As seen in the picture included, I need to find values in a column that start with "100"...so it should match anything that is '100%'

[image]

In a normal reference list where the values would be fixed I could easily write some Lookup function to say if fields A, B, and C match, then apply a value of D.

Edit: (I apologize for the lack of clarity in my question, I've tried to make improvements below)

The obstacle I'm facing is creating such a lookup list where the values aren't fixed.....so if you look at the columns in the picture the values would require Sql "like" clauses to match on certain values.

It's no problem to do this with fixed values but is this even be possible using a reference/lookup list using wildcards?

Comment: And your problem which your current query is?

Comment: Well I want to say something (obv not sql syntax) like "If the name contains "RAH" and key1 starts with and key2 = '12345' then apply a value" but for that I would have hundreds of separate rules.  I want to have a reference list that allows me to use the LIKE clause

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish here. Can you try to explain this in more detail? Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I think your best bet is to take it out of a single query and instead put the data into a data warehouse. You can run the ETL as a batch process at night and query the warehouse quickly during the day.

Comment: Attempted clarification in my original question (edit)